# d3: Adding a label next to a node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label

I am trying to add labels next to each node in my force layout graph. However, all the labels are displayed on the top left side of my screen. I looked at a lot of other stackoverflow questions with a similar problem, and I am confident in saying i tried different solutions but i still seem to have this problem. On the image below you can see all of the labels stacked together.

[image]

Here is how i initialize my nodes, images of the nodes and text:

```
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
    //.attr("transform", function(d){return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"})
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "../icons/workstation.png")
      .attr("x", -25)
      .attr("y", -25)
      .attr("width", 50)
      .attr("height", 50);

  var text = node.append("text")
        .attr("dx", ".35em")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d){ return d.ip});
```

I tried many different values for x & y and/or dx & dy but the result is the same.
And here is my on tick method, for updating the graph on tick:

```
 force.on("tick", function() {


    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

});
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle or plunker, so that we could work on it and get it.

Comment: in side your tick function remove this line `node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });` as you are already doing the transfrom

Comment: @saikiran.vsk for some reason the jsfiddle i created does not seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/0ekzmq1n/ this is the link, and all the code is inside. This is my first jsfiddle so i guess i am missing something? I am inserting D3 as a framework, but I don't see the option to insert Cola.js

Comment: are you looking for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0ekzmq1n/)

Comment: What exactly did you change? It looks the same to me, and i ran it on a script comparison tool - its the same :)

Comment: I would check (if you haven't): 1) that the text is definitely within the groups in the DOM; and 2) that the groups have x,y co-ordinates (or transform/translate) and that it is not the images that have these. The text must have co-ordinates 0,0 to be placed where it is.